# Sum the values for all similar hash keys Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, hash

Below is my code. It works (yes!), but it requires 3 loops (yikes!). Still new to coding, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient, dryer, or simply better looking way of producing the desired result. The goal is to sum the values for all similar car makes. I then store the values in a hash for each make ({"Honda" => 12400}) and then store the hashes within an array. Not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but assume down the line you will want to access the values depending on the make. I also want to *avoid hard coding* anything - assume there are 100 different makes. All advice welcome!

```
    cars = [
  {
    make: "Nissan",
    model: "Model",
    year: 2017,
    value: 5000
  },
  {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Corolla",
    year: 1997,
    value: 1000
  },
  {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Camry",
    year: 2006,
    value: 3500
  },
  {
  make: "Honda",
  model: "Accord",
  year: 2001,
  value: 5000
  },
  {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Tacoma",
    year: 2001,
    value: 2000
  },
  {
    make: "Honda",
    model: "Civic",
    year: 2001,
    value: 1200
  },
  {
    make: "Honda",
    model: "Civic",
    year: 2005,
    value: 2200
  },
  {
    make: "Honda",
    model: "Accord",
    year: 2010,
    value: 4000
  },
  {
    make: "Nissan",
    model: "Altima",
    year: 2017,
    value: 10000
  }
]

#GOAL
#Sum the values for all similar makes and store in an array with a nested hash
# sums_array = [{all_hondas: total_sum}, {all_toyotas: total_sum}]

total_value = 0
car_makes = []
cars.each{|car|
  #creates a hash with a car's make as the key and 0 as the value
  car_hash = {car[:make] => total_value}
  #shovels car_hash into an array if it does not already exist within the array
  unless car_makes.include? car_hash
    car_makes << car_hash
  end
}

values_array = []
car_makes.each {|make|
  make.each {|k, v|
    cars.each{|car|
      if car[:make] == k
        v += car[:value]
      end
    }
    values_array << {k => v}
  }
}

p values_array 

#values_array = [{"Nissan"=>15000}, {"Toyota"=>6500},{"Honda"=>12400}]
```

Comment: It's not clear why you can't iterate the array and increment a hash keyed by `make` with a running `total` value in a single loop.

Comment: What makes a make "similar"? I.e. how do you decide whether two hash keys are "similar"?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I guess better phrasing would be "if they are the same". make => "honda" is the same as make => "honda" but different than make => "nissan". Does that make sense?

Comment: Why would you want an array of the hashes instead of a hash of all the makes and totals? If you need to look one up, are you going to iterate through the array looking for the one with the correct hash key? This defeats the purpose of using a hash, doesn't it?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not sure I follow. Maybe I can and I did not think of doing that? Again, relatively new to coding so there is a good chance I am over complicating things.

Comment: @codian I'm not sure how else to explain it. Iterate the source array; each `make` gets an entry in a destination hash with an initial value of `0`. The `value` of the source array gets added to the appropriate `make` destination hash value. Destination hash is `make` => [integer value; the running total].

Comment: If your code *works* but you are looking for improvements, it might be better suited at [codereview.se]. Note: it is not off-topic on [so] per se, but over there are the experts in reviewing code and suggesting improvements. Also, the rules of their site ensure that you will actually get a *proper* review and not just a dozen "Here's how I would do it" one-liners with no explanations that don't actually teach you anything. Speaking of … `cars.group_by {|car| car[:make]}.transform_values {|cars| cars.sum {|car| car[:value]}}`.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton, I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Thanks @JörgWMittag, I'll check out Code Review. Also thanks for your input. While it doesn't teach me anything, I can still research how .transform_values, for example, works.

Comment: @codian Sounds like it does teach some things, then.

Comment: @DaveNewton Very true.

Answer (score 3):

Or in one iteration:

```
cars.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |car, hash| hash[car[:make]] += car[:value] }
#=> {"Nissan"=>15000, "Toyota"=>6500, "Honda"=>12400}
```

Docs about [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and [`Hash#new` with a default](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Hash.html#method-c-new)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was typing the same comment !!

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you, I updated my answer. Isn't it funny that the order of the block parameters is different for `inject` and `each_with_object`. This is so confusing.